# Add two decimal values

Tags: php, math, decimal, addition

so I want to add two values (money values) but can't quite work it out.

I keep getting a notice, I've tried number_format to format it but even using that I get the 'Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered'

```
$price = 0.00;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dbprice = $row["ProductSellPrice"]; 
         $price = $price + $dbprice;
        //echo number_format($price + $dbprice,2);
    }
```

however I get this problem: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

If I add two values '5' + '1.5' I get '6' as a result.

**Edit:**

The values I were pulling from the database were formatted with commas.

Comment: Have you tried checking the values for which the notice occurs?

Answer (score 3):

PHP numbers uses dot as separator and seems that you have coma. Please replace the coma with the dot as first. After that you can cast the prices into floats and finally sum it up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this (based on you example):

```
<?php
$price = 0.00;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dbprice = $row["ProductSellPrice"];
    // Replace comma. Check also for possible thousand separator.
    $dbprice = str_replace(',', '.', $dbprice);
    $price = $price + (float)$dbprice;
    //echo number_format($price + $dbprice, 2);
}
?>
```